# Setting names intuitively with dplyr across() function

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to manipulate several columns to create new columns with names that are variants of the names of the columns being manipulating.

dplyr 1.0.0's across() function seems like the tool for the job, but the .names argument seems to have limited functionality. Here's what I want to do:

```
tmp <- iris %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('Sepal'), 
                ~ .x - Petal.Length, 
                .names = gsub('Sepal', '', "{col}")))
```

but the gsub function doesn't work. I can work around this in the following way:

```
tmp <- iris %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('Sepal'), 
                ~ .x - Petal.Length, 
                .names = "mod_{col}"))

names(tmp) <- gsub("mod_Sepal", "mod_", names(tmp))
```

but that requires more code and is harder to keep track of. Am I missing something here and is there a simpler way to set the new column names with across?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rename_at` after the `mutate` step

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
iris %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('Sepal'), 
            ~ .x - Petal.Length)) %>%      
  rename_at(vars(starts_with("Sepal")), ~ str_remove(., "Sepal"))
```

---

According to `?across`

> .names - The default (NULL) is equivalent to "{col}" for the single function case

And there is no option to remove the already existing column name, but, we can add a suffix or prefix

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a function to `.names` as -

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('Sepal'), ~ .x - Petal.Length, 
                .names = "{gsub('Sepal.', '', {col}, fixed = TRUE)}")) 

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Length Width
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    3.7   2.1
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    3.5   1.6
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    3.4   1.9
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    3.1   1.6
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    3.6   2.2
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa    3.7   2.2
```